# Gitlab integration with elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, gitlab

As per gitlab documentation gitlab-ee is integrated with elastic search.
Is there any way to integrate gitlab CE with elastic search

Answer (score 0):

No, as the [requirements](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/elasticsearch.html#version-requirements) clearly state:

> GitLab Enterprise Edition 8.4 - 8.17  Elasticsearch 2.4 with Delete By
> Query Plugin installed
>
> GitLab Enterprise Edition 9.0+    Elasticsearch
> 5.1 - 5.5